# RegEx for capturing and replacing all digits in a string except for special patterns

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, regex-group

I have a text where digits appear in every possible way.
For example,

```
text = "hello23 the2e are 13 5.12apples *specially_x00123 named 31st"
```

I want to replace all digits with '#'s except the ones in a special pattern starting with *, a word, underscore, any character, and number such that *\w+_[a-z]\d+ (i.e., *specially_x00123).

I've tried to use [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) syntax and [non-capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) but can't find a way to exactly change this to as below

```
text_cleaned = "hello## the#e are ## #.##apples *specially_x00123 named ##st"
```

I can use a pattern like below:

```
p1 = r'\d(?<!\*\w+_\w+)'
```

Then, it complains like this; "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern"

I tried to use non-capturing group:

```
p2 = r'(?:\*[a-z]+_\w+)\b|\d'
```

It takes out the special token (*specially_x000123) and all the digits. I think this is something that I may include in the solution, but I can't find how. Any ideas?

Comment: @emma  the question title is edited which is not what I meant. I want to replace all the digits BUT not the ones in a special pattern such as the ones in "*specially_x000123"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex to match integers but not floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28030520/python-regex-to-match-integers-but-not-floats)

Comment: When you say ["except something" you can often use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912/5527985) which is only supported with [pypi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex). If you use that, your regex can simply be eg [`\*\S+(*SKIP)(*F)|\d`](https://regex101.com/r/F8Nz7O/1/) and replace with empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might do is capture the digit in a capturing group `(\d)` and use a callback in the replacement checking for the first capturing group.

If it is group 1, replace with a `#`, else return the match.

As `\w+` also matches an underscore, you might match a word char except the underscore first using a negeated character class `[^\W_\n]+`

```
\*[^\W_\n]+_[a-z]\d+\b|(\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZfZFat/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/K1vSDc)

```
import re
text = "hello23 the2e are 13 5.12apples *specially_x00123 named 31st"
pattern = r"\*[^\W_\n]+_[a-z]\d+\b|(\d)"
print (re.sub(pattern, lambda x: "#" if x.group(1) else x.group(), text))
```

Result

```
hello## the#e are ## #.##apples *specially_x00123 named ##st
```

Comment: Brilliant. I didn't know that I could use a lambda for a replacement string. This works with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be that we split our string to before star and then after that. The expression `(\d)` captures every digits before star, which we can simply replace using `#`, then we will be joining it with `$2`:

```
(\d)|(\*.*)
```

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(\d)|(\*.*)"

test_str = ("hello23 the2e are 13 5.12apples *specially_x00123 named\n\n"
    "hello## the#e are ## #.##apples *specially_x00123 named")

subst = "#\\2"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/racjWt/1)

```js
const regex = /(\d)|(\*.*)/gm;
const str = `hello23 the2e are 13 5.12apples *specially_x00123 named`;
const subst = `#$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: But the number of digits is not fixed. I can't just count all the numbers up to where I don't want to replace

Comment: Not relly. Yours returns ''hel# t#e are###apples *specially_x00123 named'

Comment: This works. Almost~~ 'hello## the#e are ## #.##apples #*specially_x00123 named' Now it keeps the digits in the pattern, but we have extra # at the beginning.

Comment: Ah~ Okay I see what you are doing. Let me change the question a bit. I may see digits after the special pattern.

Comment: Your regex adds adds an additional `#` in front of the star eg `*specially_`... becomes `#*specially_`... because you replace every match with `#\2` which is probably not wanted.